ubuntu 20.04 virtualbox 6.1 problem after update
Before the latest update, I was using Linux kernel 5.15.0-113 and virtualbox was ok.
VirtualBox Graphical User Interface Version 6.1.50_Ubuntu r161033
© 2004-2024 Oracle Corporation (Qt5.12.8)
After the latest update, I'm using:
Linux 5.15.0-117-generic #127~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 11 15:36:12 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
After the latest system update I can start virtualbox but all guests refuse to start.
Is this a known problem and how can I fix it?

Did you try going to advanced startup on boot and selecting the previous kernel?

No I didn't, can you describe the procedure to start the previous kernel?
I have the VBox.log file would that be of any help?

I’ve experienced the same issue after the latest update. Here’s how I resolved it:
1. Downgrade the Kernel: I found that downgrading to the previous kernel version resolved the problem with VirtualBox. Here are the commands to downgrade:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-image-5.15.0-113-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-113-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-113-generic
sudo update-grub

2. Modify GRUB Configuration: To ensure you can select the kernel version at boot, update the GRUB configuration. Edit the file /etc/default/grub and set:
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10

3. Update GRUB: Apply the changes to the GRUB configuration by running:
sudo update-grub

4. Restart the System: Reboot your computer.
5. Select the Kernel: During the boot process, select "Advanced options for Ubuntu" from the GRUB menu. Then choose the kernel version 5.15.0-113-generic from the list.
This should allow you to continue using VirtualBox without issues.
We can stop the kernel auto updates. Please check this post.
check this to see how to set the default kernel

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thanks for the advise, but is the system not going to undo these changes when a new automatic security update is received?
